# VBScript editor for MAC

Tags: macos, vbscript, editor

Is there any VBScript editor that I can run on mac? Or is VBscript something specifically for PCs?

Comment: Is there even any environment to *run* VBScript in OS X? Not that I know of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Mac, I use [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) for creating VBScripts. It doesn't support VBScript implicitly (highlighting of all keywords), but it has nice indenting, search replace etc. functions. A good all round text editor, also for code.

Of course you can not *run* the code on OSX, VBScript is for Windows environments only.

Comment: @Dan TextWrangler does support vbscript, and highlights all keywords. in order to do so, in the bottom of the editor you have to choose the language of the file (it's next to text encoding). by default, it's set to (none). click the drop-down menu and choose VBScript.

Answer (score 1):

TextWrangler (free) can be used to edit VBScript.  It does give basic syntax highlighting, strings, keywords etc, but it is not aware of App-specific object models such as the Excel Object Model, which I'm guessing is the reason you want to edit VBScript on a Mac.

Textastic ($7.99 on the AppStore as of today) has even better syntax highlighting than TextWrangler. It is syntax highlighting for ASP.NET VbScript, and that mode also works pretty well for VBA.

The built-in Visual Basic Editor in Office 2016 (for Mac) is probably the worst thing ever: no intellisense, no search/replace, no indenting and syntax highlighting is way less complete than TextWrangler or Textastic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know VBScript is just for PCs (Windows Scripting Host) and IE.